# Limit on Android version on an Android device

Tags: rom, samsung-nexus-s, 5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to make changes to the Android framework as a part of a project. As ambitious as it sounds, I want to flash a Nexus S with an Android 5 image. Can this be done, or is there a limit to the Android version supported by a device?

Comment: Do you mean Samsung Google Nexus S ? I don't think that you can flash Android Lollipop over your device. Anyway I guess better to wait a bit more while and see what other users have to talk about it !

Comment: Well you could always wait for someone at xda to port Android lollipop to nexus S(will probably happen) and then clone the device tree from them and try it out.

Comment: @HackToHell I am not sure about it but I don't think its going to arrive soon, device is almost outdated. I guess it was released over 2010, I would say there are a very little chance for something like this to happen.

Comment: Well it has kitkat http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-s/general/rom-cyanaosp-04-04-2014-t2634728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly Speaking I do not think so.

If you look on the google images for android site (https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) the highest the Nexus S goes is up to 4.1.2. Also, according to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_S) the highest modded version is 4.4.3 KitKat via the CyanogenMod. Hope this helps.